# Confusing Sprite Will Not Change

Tags: sprite, game-maker

I am working on a game with Gamemaker: Studio and have come across a little annoying problem with the sprite of the player not changing. I would like feedback as soon as possible. The sprite of "player" that is not changing is spr_playerboom. The idea is that then when the player hits Z, the sprite will change.

```
image_speed = 0.2;

var zpress = keyboard_check(ord('Z'));
var rkey = keyboard_check(vk_right);
var lkey = keyboard_check(vk_left);
var jkey = keyboard_check(vk_space);

if(zpress){
sprite_index = spr_playerboom;
}

//Check for ground
if(place_meeting(x, y+1, obj_floor)){
vspd = 0;

//Jumping
if(jkey){
vspd = -jspd;
}
} else {

//Gravity
if(vspd < 10){
vspd += grav;
}

}

//Moving right
if(rkey){
hspd = spd;
sprite_index = spr_playerwalkright;
}

//Moving left
if(lkey){
hspd = -spd;
sprite_index = spr_playerwalkleft;
}



//Check for not moving
if((!rkey && !lkey) || (rkey && lkey) || (!zpress)){
hspd = 0;
sprite_index = spr_playerstand;
}


//Horizontal Collision
if(place_meeting(x+hspd, y, obj_floor)){
while(!place_meeting(x+sign(hspd), y, obj_floor)){
    x+=sign(hspd);
}
hspd = 0;
}

//Moving Horizontally
x += hspd;




 //Vertical Collision
 if(place_meeting(x, y+vspd, obj_floor)){
 while(!place_meeting(x, y+sign(vspd), obj_floor)){
 y+=sign(vspd);
 }
 vspd = 0;
 }
 //Moving Vertically
 y += vspd;
```

Comment: Is anyone available to help?

Answer (score 1):

Let's delete the code which does not affect the sprite. Result will be:

```
var zpress = keyboard_check(ord('Z'));
var rkey = keyboard_check(vk_right);
var lkey = keyboard_check(vk_left);

if (zpress)
    sprite_index = spr_playerboom;

if (rkey)
    sprite_index = spr_playerwalkright;

if (lkey)
    sprite_index = spr_playerwalkleft;

if ((!rkey && !lkey) || (rkey && lkey) || (!zpress))
{
    sprite_index = spr_playerstand;
}
```

So there is an error. Where? The first three conditions are simple and can't conflict. So you need to check the last condition.

```
(!rkey && !lkey) || (rkey && lkey) || (!zpress)
```

it means
if `(both left and rigth keys are not pressed)` or `(both left and right keys are pressed)` or `(z key is not pressed)`. So if you pressed Z, but not pressed rkey + lkey, sprite will be changed on `spr_playerstand`, etc.

```
(((!rkey and !lkey) or (rkey and lkey)) and (!zpress))
```

in this case when Z is pressed, the sprite will not be changed on `spr_playerstand`

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe it was such a simple fix! :)